# Using a different R version with RLink

Tags: packages, interoperability, rlink

I wish to use a different version of R than what is provided by *Mathematica* 9. For example, I want to use the Macports version of R, where `R_HOME` is `/opt/local/lib/R`.

When I type:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "/opt/local/lib/R"]
```

I get the error:

```
InstallR::fail: Failed to install R. 
The following error was encountered: Unable to load dynamic libraries >>
```

(I tried to doctor up my `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but no luck.)

Comment: I'm also wondering if it is (will) be possible to update the internal R that gets downloaded from WRI to a later version (currently it's 2.14 while the latest R is 2.15).  Once we install it using `InstallR[]`, are we stuck with a particular version?

Comment: Originally I hoped that this option would work on all platforms. My initial tests indicated that it did. I had to then narrow this down to Windows for the time being, since problems on Linux and Mac were detected. This is a high-priority issue for RLink, so I hope to have more to say soon enough.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, the users are stuck with that version until we update the paclets. But I hope that the option of using own version of R will be working on other (than Windows) platforms reasonably soon, which should mitigate this situation.

Comment: **For Linux folks**: at least on some flavors of Linux, [it has been reported](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/installing-rlink-on-linux/15402#15402) that RLink works fine with the stand-alone R distribution.

Comment: Worked with me well on GNU / Linux Ubuntu 13:10 cd ~ / .Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/RLinkRuntime-Linux-x86-64-9.0.0.0/SystemFiles/Linux-x86-64/R/lib/ mv libR.so libR.so.old cp /usr/lib/libR.so .

Comment: Take a look at the first code block under "Examples" [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24545/12). This works on my OS X 10.8.3 machine with R 3.0.1, but I heard it does not work on all systems.  I am using the CRAN version of R, not the MacPorts version (is there  good reason to use the MacPorts version?).  Does it work for you?

Comment: I use Macports because a) I can select the compiler version b) easily link with accelerate c) cairo and d) automatic updates whenever R ups the version.

Comment: Well, you get a-b-c with the CRAN R version as well, but the big question is: did you get it working based on my link?

Comment: I get a nice graph.  (I modified your instructions to point to the Macports that's on my Mac, simply prepended /opt/local to the paths.  Now Macports R installs as a Framework.)  Is custom R on Mac this easy?  Thanks, I'm going to scurry off and play around with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation says](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/tutorial/UsingRLink.html#377680827), and I quote,

> **Using Your Own R Distribution (Windows only)**
>
> On Windows, it is currently possible for you to use your own R distribution with *RLink*, which may have a number of advantages in certain circumstances. For example, you already have a customized R distribution that you would like to continue using for everything, including work with *Mathematica*/*RLink*. Or, you would like to install extra packages.

So, this might be possible on Windows but not on other systems.

Comment: I would almost think that it would be easier under Mac/Linux. Meh.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Oh no, if only you knew how much time was spent to actually make this work for the R version that comes with RLink, on Linux and Mac - this took the majority of time for RLink development. I was of course building R on both Linux and Mac from sources, and doing a whole lot more to make the default R coming with RLink work without setting any env. variables. For external versions of R, it was just unfortunate that some problems with this were detected late in the develpoment, so I had no time to fix that and had to restrict this to Windows only, for the time being.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin sorry to hear that; it sounds like you had a really bad time with this! Good that you persisted, though--this seems to be the first time that WRI has really even officially acknowledged the existence of what could be seen as a competitor, let alone building comprehensive support for it into *Mathematica*. A major achievement on your part!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks! Re: bad times - one of the problems for me was that as a programmer, I am self-taught, and most of my life I was doing math / physics which did not involve any coding at all. So, some things which people with the proper CS / coding background would know or sort out quite fast, were taking me long to get resolved. But, I am getting better (I hope :)). Re: competition ackowledgement by WRI - well, I made my position on that clear to other people involved in M/R relationship assessment, but whether this had any impact on the final decision in that direction, I have no idea.

Comment: @OleksandrR thanks for letting us know that it is possible. Is it possible to know *how* it is possible?