# Using a different version of R with RLink on Windows 7

Tags: interoperability, rlink

I'd like to run the R version installed in my Windows 7 system from within Mathematica 9 but when I execute the following command:

```
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.14.2\\bin\\x64"]
```

I get the following error message:

> InstallR::fail: Failed to install R. The following error was
>   encountered: Unable to load dynamic libraries

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try to set it to the home directory of R, not the directory containing the binaries (based on the RLink docs it should point there).

Comment: @Szabolcs Why don't you make that an answer? Because that's the only sensible answer there is. And if it fails, I really want to know about it.

Comment: @Leonid I did that now.  I didn't want to post it as an answer as I don't have Mathematica 9 on Windows at the moment so I couldn't test it.  It was the first thing that came to mind though and checking the docs confirmed it.

Comment: I see that you have not [Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158428) answers to any of your questions.  Have you found *all* the answers lacking, or are you unaware of this convention on StackExchange sites?

Comment: I had the same problem, but it turned out that was because I was using R.2.10.1.
After I installed R.2.14.0, `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:/Program Files/R/R.2.14.0"]` worked fine. It also worked with R.2.15.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"RHomeLocation"` option must be set to the base directory of the R installation, not the directory containing the binaries.  Please try to set it to `C:\Program Files\R`.

Quoting the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/tutorial/UsingRLink.html):

> You can specify the location by using the `"RHomeLocation"` option to
>   `InstallR`, calling it as follows.
>
> ```
> InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "LocationOfYourRDistribution"]
> ```
>
> The value of the option should correspond to the `R_HOME` variable you
>   usually set for your R distribution, and point at the root of it.

Comment: Beware that at present, Mathematica 9 allows you to use your own R installation only on the Windows platform. On other platforms, you must use the R run-time supplied by Wolfram. (This is clearly documented, although disappointing.)

Comment: @murray Well, it has been [reported](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/installing-rlink-on-linux/15402#15402) that you can use external R on at least some flavors of Linux. I can't promise anything, but I hope to be able to address this issue for the 9.1 release.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks a lot for your answer. After following it, everything is fine now. May I suggest that the Mathematica 9 documentation is updated to put a specific example instead of the generic "LocationOfYourRDistribution"?

Comment: Unfortunately for some reason that solution does not work on my machine with Windows 7. I had just installed R from a mirror site and given the proposed `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R"]` only to receive the follwing error message: *InstallR::nopaclet: Could not find RLink runtime installed. Please use RLinkResourcesInstall to install it*. How can that be?

Comment: @gwr Does RLink work with the internal R that gets automatically downloaded the first time you use it?  What if you just do ``Needs["RLink`"]; InstallR[]``?

Comment: @Szabolcs That works fine as I just tested following your post. I seems to be an issue with releases 3.x.x of R as this thread indicates maybe: [RLink and R v3.0.1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27064/rlink-and-r-v3-0-1?rq=1)?

Comment: @gwr It looks like you found your answer, even if it's not what we hoped for ... I should have mentioned that I am not using Windows any more so I cannot actually test this.  I do use R 3.0.1 with RLink on Mac.