# Difficult R installation

Tags: installation, rlink

In [RLink and R v3.0.1?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27064/rlink-and-r-v3-0-1), there is an update which say that the problem of the lack of compatibility between the expected version and the last version of R has been settled for version  10.0.1 of Mathematica.

But I seems that this is false for version 10.0. 2 where I see the awfull screen

[image]

So, is there a   way to cope with this ?

PS More than that each tentative to Install the insider version of R --- I think an avatar of version 2 --- was solded by an echec --- it crashes at 5% --- perhaps a network problem I will try again tomorrow.

Comment: I will look into this. Starting with 10.0.1, I have added code that dispatches to the right version of the library. However, it looks like this particular combination of R and Mathematica versions is still problematic. The problem is gone is newer versions of Mathematica, I believe.