# Mathematica does not launch after RLink installation /Linux

Tags: kernel, kernel-startup, rlink

Hei,

I have a problem with Mathematica 10.0 launching after RLink installation.
I am running Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Exactly what I did:
Typed on Mathematica prompt

```
Needs["RLink`"];
RLinkResourcesInstall[]
```

`RLinkResourcesInstall` installation was successful. After this I got a complain about the dynamic libraries and then I followed the instructions presented here:

[mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/installing-rlink-on-linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/installing-rlink-on-linux)

So, I did:

```
Needs["RLink`"];
SetEnvironment["LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> "/usr/lib/R/lib"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "/usr/lib/R"]
```

After this Mathematica got stack with launching, it stops while initializing kernels. I re-installed Mathematica and in addition made following:

```
cd ~/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/RLinkRuntime-Linux-x86-64-9.0.0.0/SystemFiles/Linux-x86-64/R/bin
 chmod +x R
 cd exec
 chmod +x R
 cd ..

04 R_HOME_DIR=/home/{my username}/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/RLinkRuntime-Linux-x86-64-9.0.0.0/SystemFiles/Linux-x86-64/R
35 R_SHARE_DIR="${R_HOME_DIR}/share"
37 R_INCLUDE_DIR="${R_HOME_DIR}/include"
39 R_DOC_DIR="${R_HOME_DIR}/doc"
gedit R
```

After this nothing has changed and Mathematica does not launch. Before RLink installation it worked. In addition I cannot `kill`

```
3900 pts/0    00:00:00 mathematica
3973 pts/0    00:00:04 Mathematica
3984 pts/0    00:00:59 WolframKernel
4119 pts/0    00:00:00 WolframKernel
```

Comment: Try searching this same SE for a question regarding *Mathematica* freezing on Initializing kernels and follow the steps outlined there.

Comment: Thanks for the help !
The suggestions in a following link helped:

<http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/mathematica-10-0-x-freezes-in-initializing-kernels>