# Problems with RLink; Debian Wheezy, external R version 2.15.1

Tags: rlink

Hei,

I am still in stuck with `InstallR`. I followed the instructions presented in a link:

[Installing RLink on Linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/installing-rlink-on-linux)

but still no result.

I am running Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Mathematica 10.0 and the external R `R version 2.15.1`. Setting the explicit R version on Mathematica prompt did not help:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
SetEnvironment["LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> "/usr/lib/R/lib"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "/usr/lib/R", "RVersion" -> 2.15]
```

Comment: Read that linked answer carefully. You may have to install extra libraries, for certain Linux flavors. It is described on some of the answers there.

Comment: Yep, thanks ! 
In spite it did not complain about any missing libraries I installed ` compat-libf2c-34-3.4.6-9.x86_64.rpm `. 
This .rpm library can be found:

(http://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/fedora/linux/releases/9/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/compat-libf2c-34-3.4.6-9.x86_64.rpm)

The link advised in the answer is deprecated. It seems that after the library installation RLink started to work.

Comment: Glad it helped. When I work on RLink again (but it's hard to tell when that would be), I will see if this library issue can be addressed and automated. It does not show up on all Linux flavors though.